# How do I use ajax to post form data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

How can I use ajax to post value from user input to my web service api?
It seems that I can't append value at ajax url.

The following is my code...

```
 <form action="javascript:Start()">
      <input type="text" id="target" value="tar"/>
      <input type="text" id="profile" value="pro"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

---

```
  function Start()
    {
        var target = $('#target').val();
        var profile = $('#profile').val();

        if(validateIdata())
        {
            $.ajax({    
              type: 'POST',
              url: "webapi/"+ target + "/" + profile,
              data: $form.serialize(),
              success: function(){
                alert('success');
              }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve it passing data on URL instead of data field. Try this.

Html. (add `id` to form in order to access later to its data)

```
<form id="form" action="javascript:Start()">
      <input type="text" id="target" value="tar"/>
      <input type="text" id="profile" value="pro"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript.

```
function Start()
    {
        var target = $('#target').val();
        var profile = $('#profile').val();

        if(validateIdata())
        {
            $.ajax({    
              type: 'POST',
              url: "webapi/"+ target + "/" + profile?+$('#form').serialize(),
              success: function(){
                alert('success');
              }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: That correctly except I only use this [0] to done my job.



[0]url: "webapi/"+ target + "/" + profile

Answer (score 2):

You are serialising all the successful form controls, but your form doesn't have any controls that can be successful. They need to have `name` attributes.

This assumes that you have defined `$form` somewhere, you haven't in the code you have shared, if you haven't then you need to do that first.